# Moving the browser view around a huge html page without using scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, view

I've got a very huge html page (like 7000*5000) and i'd need to move the user's view around that page with javascript.

I can easily unable the user to move around by himself by removing the browser scrollbars (with overflow:hidden on html), what i need to do next is to control the movement of the "camera" around that huge page in js/jquery.

I didn't found anything on the web even if I searched a lot, apart from using anchors with smooth jQuery scrolling, which is OK (even if not very neat) to move in a vertical way, but then it becomes very complicated to do it horizontally.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Mark the question as answer which works perfect for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery scrollTo and localScroll plugins are perfectly suited to this. Take a look here: http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html for the options and here for a demo: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

The plugins allow you to queue the animation and define settings for scrolling horizontally and vertically at the same time, or vertically then horizontally, etc.

Neal

Comment: Thanks a lot for that i'm going to work into it, I already saw those plugins but I didn't realize theycould do horizontal and even diagonal scrolls.
Anyway, is there a 'direct' way of controlling the viewport ? Like to do a moveright(100) function to move the browser window on the right of 100px ?
Sure with scrolling plugins i could scroll to some divs which i could then move, but this is not very neat in my opinion.
Thanks again

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to use those plugins to create a fluid scrolling system, with a scroll +100Px in 100ms called every 100ms. The problem is that it works well on my pc, but if I try it on a less powerful one like a netbook, it runs a bit slowly and the scrolling queue up. How to disable queue/ optimize the scrolling ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your main surrounding element, div or section if you actually have one, set it too fixed. Instead of actually scrolling in the browser's window just reposition what you have on the screen and give the effect of scrolling. User won't know the difference.

Comment: you can select from many similar approaches like using position relative, position absolute, or negative margin on the content div

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery's animate function. Maybe you could do something like this:

```
function movePage(newTop, newLeft){
    $('#pageview').animate({left:newLeft + "px", top: newTop + "px"});
}
```

Please update your question with an explanation of *when* you want to move the page around and I can try and help you some more.

Answer (score 0):

If your [content overflows its surrounding rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements), you still can scroll it with JS - regardless whether there are scrollbars shown or not by CSS.

For the whole window, you can use [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo) and its derivatives.

For single DOM elements, this can be accomplished by setting the [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft) and [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) properties.

With both methods you will be able to build a (jQuery) animation, surely there are already some plugins for achieving that. I found [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.de/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) for example, but maybe the built-in methods [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) and [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) are enough for your purposes. In the [comments](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/#dsq-comment-77972155) also something like

```
 $(someSelector).animate({scrollLeft: someNumber}, 'slow');
```

is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something of your own, you can do something like this,

```
var targetOffset = $('#post-10').offset().top ;
var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

$(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
    // scroll is complete
      location.hash = 'post-10';
});

   // Use the first element that is "scrollable"  (cross-browser fix?)
function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
        var el = arguments[i],
        $scrollElement = $(el);
        if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
            return el;
        } else {
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
            var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
            if (isScrollable) {
                return el;
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

This is for vertical scroll.

For horizontal scroll, you can do,

```
  var targetOffset = $('#post-10').offset().left ;
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

    $(scrollElem).animate({scrollLeft: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
        // scroll is complete
          location.hash = 'post-10';
    });
```

I would highly recommend this plugin for nice horizontal/vertical scrolls with a lot of effects.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/